# Is there a plugin to help with translation of other plugins?

Tags: plugins

I remember seeing a plugin that helps with the translation of other plugins. Anyone remember the name of that plugin? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Over years I tried and used lots of wordpress multilanguge solutions and at this moment the [WordPress MultiLanguage](http://wpml.org/) plugin (WPML) seams to be the best.

One of the features supported is the translations of the plugins.

Answer (score 2):

> You can manage and edit all gettext translation files (*.po/*.mo) directly out of WordPress Admin Center without any need of an external editor. [Codestyling Localization](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/codestyling-localization/)

Comment: (+1) Also IMHO it is definitely the best solution . Further more - as a side note I might add that it is an impressively good and complete plugin (codewise)